# What's default response format if multiple format specified for: TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I had the following setting in the django app:

```
TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS = ['json', ]
```

and the response format was JSON. Then it was changed to:

```
TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS = ['json', 'xml', ]
```

and unfortunately default response format switched to XML.

Why? What is the default format if multiple formats are specified and there's no *accept* header set in HTTP request?

[Here](https://github.com/phalt/pokeapi/pull/21) the problem I'm asking about, can be found.